# Compilation failed while trying to run Chart Clicker

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am trying to make [Chart Clicker](http://gphat.github.com/chart-clicker/) works in Perl. I have downloaded the example `pie.pl`. And I have configured everything by installing all the modules properly. But whenever I try to run the `pie.pl example`. I get the below exception. Can anyone suggest me why is it happening and how can I overcome this?

```
C:\Perl64\site>perl pie.pl
Subroutine share_axes_with redefined at lib/Chart/Clicker/Context.pm line 120.
The 'add_attribute' method cannot be called on an immutable instance at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Class/MOP/Class/Immutable/Trait.pm line 32.
        Class::MOP::Class::Immutable::Trait::_immutable_cannot_call('add_attribute') called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Class/MOP/Class/Immutable/Trait.pm l
ine 47
        Class::MOP::Class:::around('CODE(0x35683d8)', 'Class::MOP::Class::Immutable::Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x5833518)', 'domain_axis', 'default', 'C
ODE(0x3dd85d0)', 'is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Chart::Clicker::Axis', ...) called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Class/MOP/Method/Wrapped.pm line 162
        Class::MOP::Method::Wrapped::__ANON__('Class::MOP::Class::Immutable::Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x5833518)', 'domain_axis', 'default', 'CODE(0x3d
d85d0)', 'is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Chart::Clicker::Axis', 'definition_context', ...) called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Class/MOP/Method/Wrapped.pm line 91
        Class::MOP::Class::Immutable::Moose::Meta::Class::add_attribute('Class::MOP::Class::Immutable::Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x5833518)', 'domain_ax
is', 'default', 'CODE(0x3dd85d0)', 'is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Chart::Clicker::Axis', 'definition_context', ...) called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Moose.pm line 79

        Moose::has('Class::MOP::Class::Immutable::Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x5833518)', 'domain_axis', 'is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Chart::Clicker::Axis', 'defa
ult', 'CODE(0x3dd85d0)') called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Moose/Exporter.pm line 382
        Moose::has('domain_axis', 'is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Chart::Clicker::Axis', 'default', 'CODE(0x3dd85d0)') called at lib/Chart/Clicker/Context.pm line
 41
        require lib/Chart/Clicker/Context.pm called at pie.pl line 5
        main::BEGIN() called at lib/Chart/Clicker/Context.pm line 0
        eval {...} called at lib/Chart/Clicker/Context.pm line 0
Compilation failed in require at pie.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at pie.pl line 5.
```

If anyone need more information for any file. Please let me know, I will upload that file.

Comment: With a bit of luck out-commenting `__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;` in `lib/Chart/Clicker/Context.pm` could help. But that may break other things… This is a really interesting question.

Comment: I tried commenting out, but it doesn't works for me and it breaks other thing and I got some more errors afterwards.

Comment: Well, what seems to be happening is that `Context.pm` tries to build a class and *then* declare it final (emulating final classes in Java). But your error message says that the class was finalized before anything else, so it can't be built programmatically (with the `has` function of Moose). I have the feeling somebody might have messed with BEGIN blocks, but I don't have the slightest idea why this didn't happen when the module was tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you need to run `moose-outdated`.  This is a script that comes with [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/), and running it will produce a list of modules (if any) that are incompatible with the version of Moose you have installed.  Upgrade those modules.

Comment: From where and How I can run this script and where I can find it?

Comment: @rjchar, it should have been installed automatically when you installed Moose.  Try typing `moose-outdated` at your shell.  Failing that, extract the Moose tarball, `cd` into it, and type `perl bin/moose-outdated`.

Comment: I tried executing `moose-outdated` and nothing happens. And then after that when I tried executing `perl pie.pl` I got same error again as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: @rjchar, if `moose-outdated` produces no output, then outdated MooseX modules are not the problem; it's something else.