# Using Perl to draw a Pie chat and bar graph

Tags: perl, graph

I need to make a Pie Chart and Bar graph using Perl. I need to make two graphs something like below using Perl[image]

Which libraries I can use here? As Previously I was trying to work with `Chart Clicker` and I was not able to make that work. There was some error coming up in some Modules. I posted same question few weeks back and nobody has answered yet [Compilation failed while trying to run Chart Clicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788445/compilation-failed-while-trying-to-run-chart-clicker#comment15661146_11788445).

So that is the reason I was looking for some simple libraries from which I can draw the above two graphs in Perl

Comment: The question you reference has an answer.

Comment: But if you see the discussion in that answer, you will find it is some other problem with the modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [GD::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GDGraph/Graph.pm) - Graph Plotting Module for Perl 5, would be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil for the suggestion. Can you point me to any link in which it is clearly mentioned how to install GD::Graph library in windows and unix both? It will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: did you find any problem while installing the module? I have used the modules some years back and i think at that time it was installing and working perfectly.